# How check what program is reading/writing to disk and registry

Tags: windows, registry, disk

Is there possibility to check which files program is using from disk (saving/reading to them) and check what program is reading from registry and saving to registry?

This is a common software development task, especially when supporting legacy software or debugging issues in closed-source software

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably many tools, but Microsoft provides [ProcMon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) (AKA Process Monitor) which should do what you want.